# Python - Restart program automatically

Tags: python, restart

I am looking for restarting a program automatically, exactly if I was clicking on "Run" or "F5" to execute the program, when this one is already open.
The idea would be to close the program, to start it again, but automatically.
I found lot of similar questions, but nothing works very well, sometimes it opens a new window (with the background in black, over the console), and in this case (see code below) it starts again but with shell.
For this program I would like that when it starts again, the program asks me the value of "x" I wish again, without opening an other window when reexecuting the program.

Thanks for the help (I use Python 3.10.0 on Windows 10).

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

x=int(input("x = "))

if x==0:

##    subprocess.call(["bash", "-c", "source ~/.profile; " + "test.py"])

    os.execl(sys.executable, '"{}"'.format(sys.executable), *sys.argv)

else:print("fin")
```

Comment: can I ask... why? what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? If you just want to take repeated user input, then a loop is the best way to do that

Comment: This program is just a simple example to understand the method, in my main program I really need to restart the program when the user changes an option.

Comment: That's why I can not use a loop, or any function to call to reexecute a specific part of the program

Comment: What happens when the user changes an option that means you MUST restart the Python script? The only things I can think of is switching Python interpreter or something like that

Comment: you need to have once more script that basically opens the script and runs and close it and run again. Or you can keep it kind of a flask API to execute the function whenever you hit the API, feedbacks are welcome.

Comment: ok thank you !!! I will try the method with an other script to run and close the other again